# Trying to target a UL in a DIV with some CSS (I can't create a class though)

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="facetwp-selections">
  <ul>
    <li data-facet="countries">USA</li>
    <li data-facet="countries">UK</li>
    <li data-facet="countries">Germany</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to make the indentation zero.

Usually, this is very simple like:

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

However, there are other UL items on the same page and I do not have control in being able to add a class to the UL I am trying to target.

I thought that this would work but it didn't:

```
ul.facetwp-selections {
    padding: 0;
}
```

And I tried this too:

```
facetwp-selections.ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Any other way to target the UL in the parent DIV?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```css
.facetwp-selections > ul{
    padding: 0;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="facetwp-selections">
  <ul>
    <li data-facet="countries">USA</li>
    <li data-facet="countries">UK</li>
    <li data-facet="countries">Germany</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="facetwp-selections2">
  <ul>
    <li data-facet="countries">USA</li>
    <li data-facet="countries">UK</li>
    <li data-facet="countries">Germany</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

try like this, here is the actual parent's child CSS syntax, for more refer[parents child css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator#:%7E:text=The%20child%20combinator%20(%20%3E%20)%20is,elements%20matched%20by%20the%20first.&text=Elements%20matched%20by%20the%20second%20selector%20must%20be%20the%20immediate,matched%20by%20the%20first%20selector.)

And here is working fidlle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/f4dat9p3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your css should be something like

```
.facetwp-selections ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
.facetwp-selections ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="facetwp-selections">
  <ul>
    <li data-facet="countries">USA</li>
    <li data-facet="countries">UK</li>
    <li data-facet="countries">Germany</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```